# How can I recreate a collection with all the indexes?

Tags: mongodb, integration-testing, spring-data

To run all my tests in isolation I would like to drop and recreate a MongoDb collection every time a test method is called, reading the POJO annotations. The problem is that it seems the indexes are created only when MongoTemplate class is instantiated.

This is perfect for the "normal" application, but during the integration testing I would like to have a test like this (maybe too slow for real applications...):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {
    ApplicationConfig.class, 
    MongoConfiguration.class,
    TestMongoConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BookServiceIntegrationTests {
    private @Autowired TestHelper testHelper;

    @Before
    public void startup() {
        testHelper.init(Book.class);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        testHelper.drop(Book.class);
    }

    //test methods...
}
```

And this is my pretty straightforward POJO class:

```
@Document(collection = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String genre;

    private List<String> tags;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

Checking the sources for Spring Data for MongoDB (1.0.1.RELEASE) I saw that the class MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator is reading the POJO annotations and ensuring the indexes for the colletion. This class is called only inside the MongoTemplate constructor.

Do you think I can find a better way to simulate something like a rollbacked transaction in my tests ?

Thanks,
Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit because I can see you want to read the annotations, so what follows might be something you've already tried. If you can live with scripting the collection outside of Java, you can try this approach:

Use mongodump and mongorestore using a system runtime exec from Java.

Firstly, take a snapshot of your test collection:

```
/usr/bin/mongodump -d yourDB -c books
```

Then in the setup of your JUnit test, restore the collection, dropping the old one first with the --drop option.

```
/usr/bin/mongorestore --drop -d yourDB -c books dump/yourDB
```

This should restore the indexes at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. This would be the second step: loading test data before the test suite is executed. I will try to add these commands to my gradle script.